# How do I properly set up this optimization equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, optimization

So I've been the given the task to fully optimize any packaging. I chose a DS game box. So first I took the measurements of the cartridge itself ($3.5 \text{ cm} \times 3.3 \text{ cm} \times 0.38 \text{ cm}$). The volume of this game is $4.3\text{ cm}^3$.

So instead of using three variables I decided to make the length and the width ratios of each other. $\frac{3.5\text{ cm}}{3.3\text{ cm}}=\frac{35}{33}$

So...

Constraint: 
$4.3=\frac{35}{33}x \times (x) \times (y)$

Where $y= \frac{4.3}{\frac{35}{33}x^2}$

Then my optimization equation for the surface area was
$SA=2\big(\frac{35}{33x}(x)\big) + 2\big(\frac{35}{33x}(y)\big) + 2\big(xy\big)$

I then did what I normally do for an optimization question where I expanded and then took the derivative of that equation. I then set that derivative to $0$ and solved for $x$, however the answer I received was completely unreasonable.

So disregarding the practicality of optimizing the packaging of a DS game to shrink fit the game, where did I go wrong?

Comment: What are you optimizing for? As in, what do you want to be a variable?

Comment: @Shahar I'm optimizing for X, and then with x I can find Y. Essentially I want to find the smallest possible surface area (using calculus).

Comment: Well I got that, but what are the constants? Right now, you're telling me you have a box with set dimensions and thus a set surface area... What quantities are variable (i.e. the width/height/etc.).

Comment: @Shahar the width and the height would be variable quantities I believe.

Comment: Length is constant then? Can you post the problem you got or that the teacher posed?

Comment: @Shahar it's a very open ended question. No real problem was given. We were just told to optimize some packaging.

Comment: Well that's weird then. If you can find me an actual problem to solve, then that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to do, the formulation of your question will be that you want to minimize ( or maximize) the surface of a cuboid up to a fixed volume :

let me tell you that in practice your problem have to add some constraints about the dimension (the geometry) of what you want put it in.

your objective function is : 
$$f(x,y,z)= 2(xy+xz+yz)$$
 and your constraint is 
$$xyz=\alpha$$ 
( $\alpha$ is a fixed positive number, for your problem $\alpha= 4.3$ )

if you want to maximize, your problem will be meaningless, because, for example, when x became very small y and z in some way have to be very large to hold the volume fix and your f reach infinity.

if you want to minimize you can consider in the first time, the function $f$ with fixed $x$ $(x=x_0)$ : and minimize the function 
$$f(y)=x_0y+\frac{\alpha}{x_0}+\frac{\alpha}{y}$$
 The study of this function will give that we have a minimum at the point $y*=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{x_0}}$ after that you try to find the minimum of the function 
$$x_0 \longmapsto f(y*)$$

you will find that we have a minimum at the point $x_0=\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}$

so you find out that : $$x=y=z=\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}$$